# Turn off Accepting Responses on a Google Form via a script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to programmatically turn off Accepting Responses for a standard Google Form through a Google Apps Script?

Comment: I don't think you can, almost nothing exist to handle /modify or activate google standard forms... you could enter a feature / enhancement request on the issue tracker

Comment: You can now, with Form Services (May 2013).

Answer (score 0):

The recently released Forms Service provides this capability, through the [setAcceptingResponses()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setAcceptingResponses%28Boolean%29) function.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, but only for old Google Forms. Here's an instruction: http://cloudlab.newvisions.org/scripts/formlimiter

It can limit responses bases on number of responses, a time/date and probably very handy: a specific cell value. This way you can for instance add up a column (like "how many people is your group") and use a SUM-cell value to close the form)

It's about time someone made all this possible (preferrably as a regular function) in the new Forms...

Comment: The example refers to old spreadsheets, not old forms. The script should also work in new SS but I didn't test it.